# JS/JQ: Schrodinger's array? How can an array be empty and not empty at the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, firefox

I have a javascript function that returns an array of objects. The array looks like this: [array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNZcX.png)

I want to use $.each() to iterate through the array and do some things with the objects' properties. However, $.each() doesn't fire at all. For example, this:

```
myArray = myFunc();
$.each(myArray, function(index, object){
    console.log('testing testing 1 2 3');
}
```

doesn't do anything at all. No console.logs.

However, if I do this:

```
myArray = myFunc();
console.dir(myArray);
$.each(, function(index, object){
    console.log('testing testing 1 2 3');
}
```

in Firefox it produces the output shown above - I can see all the objects in the array just fine.

However, console.log() shows simply

```
Array [   ]
```

How is it possible for the array to simultaneously be empty, AND have contents that console.dir() can show?

FWIW, this ugly mess is what the function (generated in part by PHP) ends up looking like:

```
            instance = false;
            function checkMessages() {
                var messageArray = [];
                $('#newMessages').html('0');
                if (!instance) {
                    instance = true;
                    myMessages = 0;
                    myRead = 0;
                    delete data;
                    $.ajax({
                        type : 'POST',
                        url : 'Chat/process.php',
                        data : {
                            'function' : 'getState',
                            'filename' : 'data/chat_2_1.txt',
                        },
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function(data){
                            myMessages = data.state;
                            messageArray[2] = {
                                'filename' : 'chat_2_1.txt',
                                'divname' : 'msg_2',
                                'length' : data.state,
                            };
                        },
                    }).done(function(){
                        delete data;
                        $.ajax({
                            type : 'POST',
                            url : 'Chat/process.php',
                            data : {
                                'function' : 'getReadByMe',
                                'filename' : 'log/chat_2_1_2.txt',
                            },
                            dataType: 'json',
                            success: function(data){
                                messageArray[2].read = data.read;
                            },
                        });


                    });
                    myMessages = 0;
                    myRead = 0;
                    delete data;
                    $.ajax({
                        type : 'POST',
                        url : 'Chat/process.php',
                        data : {
                            'function' : 'getState',
                            'filename' : 'data/chat_3_1.txt',
                        },
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function(data){
                            myMessages = data.state;
                            messageArray[3] = {
                                'filename' : 'chat_3_1.txt',
                                'divname' : 'msg_3',
                                'length' : data.state,
                            };
                        },
                    }).done(function(){
                        delete data;
                        $.ajax({
                            type : 'POST',
                            url : 'Chat/process.php',
                            data : {
                                'function' : 'getReadByMe',
                                'filename' : 'log/chat_3_1_2.txt',
                            },
                            dataType: 'json',
                            success: function(data){
                                messageArray[3].read = data.read;
                            },
                        });
                    });                     
                    instance = false;
                    return messageArray;
                } else {
//                  setTimeout(checkMessages({}), 500);
                }

            }



            $(document).ready(function(){
                console.log('foo');
                myMessageArray = checkMessages([]);
                console.log(myMessageArray);
                $.each(myMessageArray, function(i, obj){
                    console.log('compare?');
//                  compareRead(Number(obj['length']), Number(obj['read']), obj['divname']);
                });
//              setInterval(checkMessages(), 500);
            });
```

Comment: `$.ajax()` operations  are **asynchronous**.  The function calls return before the HTTP operations have completed.

Comment: Well geez, that certainly explains a lot. So I should maybe move the what-I-want-to-do-with-the-array code to a .done() function on the second ajax operation?

Comment: Second each call seems to be missing something

Comment: Thanks, @Pointy, that completely did the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function is asynchronous. use the synchronous version or use a callback

```
 $.ajax({..... other properties .... ,
        async: false })
```

Comment: You're right, I was totally failing to get the whole asynchronous part. Thanks!